# Does deleting a downvoted answer that you made cause you to lose rep?

Tags: support, reputation

I deleted [this answer](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/22928/how-to-install-google-music-on-a-non-us-phone/22935#22935), which had been downvoted once. I just checked, and it seems I have lost another 6 rep for removing it.

I never knew deleting answers removed rep. Can someone please confirm?

Comment: You have enough rep to see the upvote and downvote count on a post, just move your cursor on the count digit of rep and click it and you will see the up/downvote.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's actually sitting at +1 / -2, which gives you `1*10 + 2*-2 = 6` rep.

Negative net rep from posts is always removed when you delete them, and positive net rep is also removed if the post is [below +3 or younger than 2 months](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/124805/154510).

Comment: Ah, that makes sense. Thanks :)